# Trouble passing directories into java application via command line

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I am attempting to pass a few directories to my java application via cmd line.

These are the two directories:

\##############\Valuations\Production\CMRM-VC-FI\Bondzilla-Snaps\April 2016\
\#########\Home\A#######\Desktop\autorbtest.csv
(I have blacked out some parts of the directory)

Because the first directory has a space near the end, java interprets the first directory as two separate args. I have attempted to put double quotes around the directories (") but java still interprets the space as a separate arg.

I am thinking that it has something to do with the double backslash at the beginning of the directories.

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: You should show the code that is parsing the the input

Comment: well the arguments are being passed into a main function. main function in java accepts 1 argument which is string[] args. java loads the arguments into an array, I do not parse the input. The way java interprets the arguments is simply through spaces. Showing my code here would not be of much relevance here i think

Comment: Of course it would be of much relevance. We review code here, not directory structures. Nobody will (be able to) help you without any code.

Comment: regardless of what my app does with the arguments, if the arguments are not being parsed by java properly, then that has absolutely nothing to do with my code. So again, not relevant to throw in a bunch of code for no reason. Dont want to complicate things. Another user has provided an answer that works beautifully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing, based upon the above input, that when using the quotes around the path with the space, that ends with a backslash, that actually the OP received **one** parameter rather than two. Quoting a path with spaces will work, though it won't if the final path ends with a backslash. May Windows be forever cursed for using a backslash as the path separator.

To specify the path ##############\Valuations\Production\CMRM-VC-FI\Bondzilla-Snaps\April 2016\, you will need to do

```
java WHAT_EVER_ARGS CLASSNAME "\##############\Valuations\Production\CMRM-VC-FI\Bondzilla-Snaps\April 2016\\" "other file"
```

As a check you could add in the `main` method:

```
    int i = 0;
    for (String arg : args) {
        System.out.printf("[%d]: %s%n", i++, arg);
    }
```

You should see the number of expected arguments. If you do not double the trailing backslash, you will seen only a single output.

Example when the parameters are: `"\somePath\Has a Space\At end\" "\someother\Path\Here"`

> [0]: \somePath\Has a Space\At end" \someother\Path\Here

Example when the parameters are: `"\somePath\Has a Space\At end\\" "\someother\Path\Here"`

> [0]: \somePath\Has a Space\At end\
>   [1]: \someother\Path\Here

Comment: could one also just do \##############\Valuations\Production\CMRM-VC-FI\Bondzilla-Snaps\"April 2016"\

Comment: @karina, indeed one could, but it gets more complicated if there are multiple segments with spaces in them, since it would potentially require quoting multiple segments. I personally do not believe it is necessary to have the trailing slash at all, but that is a different story.

Comment: i also agree with not needing the trailing slash but i guess the biggest concern is that this is technically user input... it could be anything.